# OpenCv gesture identification

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on opencv gesture identification and have hit a small snitch.
Suppose i am showing the number 3..the webcam identifies 3.
What i have done is print the number 3 or write the text 3 on the image.
However..due to minute variations..the output changes in small intervals of time..hence fluctuations arise.showing 2 for 0.1 second..and 3 for the next 1 second.
I need some help to find a way to display..say the average number for a certain period of time(average rounded off to the nearest integer)
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

how about some kind of lowpass filter. A concrete implementation of that would be a weighted average. (This is the direct answer to your question)
But regarding that the fluctuations are unwanted artifacts I would recommend to set a hard treshold regarding the minimum time interval a number has to be found over serveral images. 
e.g. you want to detect a three, but the two will appear serveral times for lets say less than a second -> you only want to update the displayed number if the new number was detected for more than 1 second.

Comment: yea for example you could check if the "3" appears in any 7 out of 10 frames and keep rolling that 10 frame window, dropping the first frame and adding a new frame as it streams in.

Comment: The problem is there is very minute chance that a number will occur continously for that period of time(1 second) out of 50 frames however..40 will be the number desired..and the others wrong..i need to find a way to filter this

Comment: Then do it frame based instead of timebased as supposed from mobooya.